# How does lactate produced in the intestines get transported to the rest of the body?

Tags: bacteriology, immune-system

Some gut bacteria known as lactic acid bacteria(LAB) are known to produce lactate in the intestines and they confer beneficial effects such as enhancement of the immune system, but I assume not all of the lactate stay in the intestines and some of them will get transported to the rest of the body and used by other tissues (e.g. cori cycle). If that's the case, do these lactate enter the circulatory system? Are there any articles reporting it?